# SIMILAR TO predicate ingres 4gl issue

Tags: mysql, sql, ingres, 4gl

I used this query to get a regular expression with successful results.

```
select * from paso_string where 'AAAAAAAAA' SIMILAR TO columname
```

But, When I use this query into ingres 4GL show me an error when I try to compiling  and show me the follow issue.

> E_OS0100 Syntax error on line 
>   The last symbol read was 'similar'

Comment: please make up your mind on which databases you're using.

Comment: `SIMILAR TO` is a PostgreSQL and Firebird thing. It's not in MySQL. Your error message shows that it's not in Ingres. Please don't spam us by tagging your question with all sorts of DBMS maker tags for DBMSs you are not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4GL has its own parser, which sadly is often behind the SQL parser when it comes to new features.

The standard work-around is to put your SQL statement into a string and then do **execute immediate :string;**

Comment: I'm editing my code using execute immediate. I will post the results more later. Thanks for all your comments